# Export Link returned by DriveService.Files.Get(uid) fails with HTML 400 error returned

Tags: google-drive-api

We have been using the Files.Get(uid) function on the DriveService in the .net client library for drive for at least 6 months and it has been working as expected.

May 3 2021 (yesterday) at approximately 2pm EST, we began getting the following response from the api (the response is html and contains this error:

...

The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That’s all we know.

The link returned is :

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id={sheetuid}&exportFormat=xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=%7Bsheetuid%7D&exportFormat=xlsx)

But this link returns the above error.

If we instead build the link ourselves:

[https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{sheetuid}/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%7Bsheetuid%7D/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)

The call returns a stream as expected as it used to until yesterday, and is successful.

This is impacting many of our clients in production- is this a known issue that will be resolved?

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: I could confirm the same situation with you. Although the export method of Drive API can be used, other endpoint cannot be used now. I'm not sure whether this is the temporal issue. (I want to believe that this is the temporal situation.) I apologize for this. And, I couldn't still find this issue at the issue tracker. So how about reporting this to the issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

Comment: This appears to have resolved itself at the moment, the error is no longer thrown...