# Google Drive File download through Oauth2

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am getting below error while using Google API.
URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=${document_id}&exportFormat=${format}&format=${format}
```

- Method: GET
- Result format: File

Error:

> Unauthorized (401) - The request requires user authentication (1 attempt)

we retrieve access token with help of refresh_token, client_id and client_secret key

while externally (except RunMyProcess portal) received 307 status code

> Temporary Redirect (307) - The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI

we just wanted to clarify about API. Is this API has been changed?

Cannot find Google API documentation for same.

[image]

Comment: I thought that your situation might be the same with this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67385776

Comment: Yes the same scenario with me. The Endpoint URL was not available whole day on 4th May 2021. Now its working fine.  But I want to understand the error occurred as it impact our most of the customers as well as we face the same issue last year same time. 
@Tanaike